# How can I turn categories into columns with percentage results?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, data-analysis

I am new to data analysis and would like to know if I can display the following categories as columns with percentage values.  I am using Python pandas for the analysis.

I have the following data set:

| Country | Geographical extent |
| --- | --- |
| Austria | Local |
| Austria | Regional |
| Austria | Regional |
| Austria | National |
| Belgium | Local |
| Belgium | Local |
| Belgium | Regional |
| Belgium | Regional |

I would like to get the following result:

| Country | Local | National | Regional |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Austria | 25 | 25 | 50 |
| Belgium | 50 | 0 | 50 |

Since there are a lot of countries in the data set, I would like to know if there is an easy way to implement this.

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, try: `pd.crosstab(df['Country'], df['Geographical extent'], normalize='index').mul(100)`.